# RecyclerView with CardView getting performance issues

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm the new RecyclerView with the CardView layout from the android support library but i'm experiencing very low frame rate when scrolling.
Is the issue coming from my adapter or is it a known issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it !
Turned out that loading the drawable through the xml layout file was the issue. When loading the image with the [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) framerate got way better.

Comment: Try Glide too. For me it's much faster. Loading images from device.